# Ubuntu is installed but not booting.I am using a windows 8 pre-installed laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

Ubuntu is installed but not booting and is appearing in OS choice but when i choose Ubuntu it shows cannot find file   **ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr**

I am using a windows 8 pre-installed laptop.

I installed it using LiveDVD but i am not able to boot.

Do I need to change BIOS settings ?

Answer (score 0):

the new windows 8 computer tends to have UEFI as a BIOS replacement and in that case you should use a different kind of partitioning and system for loading OS (instead of MBR): have you checked if your windows 8 computer is using UEFI?

Comment: yes i have checked.

Comment: and, what's the result? is it uefi?